# How to access member variables sqlite callback

Tags: c++, oop, sqlite

I need access variables in class from sqlite callback function. It cannot be static because i need acces this variables from other functions. This is my current code.

```
class fromdb {
private:
   string paramdb;
   char* errmsg;
   string param;
   string title;
   string creator;
   char* bin;
public:
     static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
        int lenght;
        lenght = sizeof(*argv[3]);
        title = *argv[1];
        creator = *argv[2];
        bin = new char[lenght];
        bin = argv[3];
        return 0;
}
void getdata() {
string tQuery = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE " + paramdb + "=\"" + param + "\" )";
  sqlite3_exec(db, tQuery.c_str(), fromdb::callback, (void*)data, &errmsg);
}
};
```

logs

```
undefined reference to `fromdb::title[abi:cxx11]'
undefined reference to `fromdb::creator[abi:cxx11]'
undefined reference to `fromdb::bin'
```

Comment: Pass the `this` pointer of the class through the _1st argument to callback parameter_ see: https://sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html

Comment: `bin = new char[lenght]; bin = argv[3];` Why do you allocate memory only to leak it on the next line?

Comment: After changing to sqlite3_exec(db, tQuery.c_str(), this->callback, (void*)data, &errmsg); I have this error: /root/Dokumenty/musicdb/funcs.h|94|error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘int fromdb::callback(void*, int, char**, char**)’|

Comment: Edit the question to show the entire code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting undefined references because you are attempting to use non-static members from a static function.

> It cannot be static because I need access this variables from other functions

You can still use a `static` function, but you need to pass a member in, as [@Richard Critten points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015168/how-to-access-member-variables-sqlite-callback#comment78990577_46015168), or you can use a `friend` function.

Here I've created a more simple version of your code to demonstrate, using a `static` function like you have, but passing in the member variable:

```
class artwork
{
private:
    std::string title;
    std::string creator;
public:
    static int populateFromDB(void* object, int, char** data, char**)
    {
        if (artwork* const art= static_cast<artwork*>(object))
        {
            art->title = data[1];
            art->creator = data[2];
        }
        return 0;
    }
};

artwork a;
char* error = nullptr;
if (sqlite3_exec(db, tQuery.c_str(), &artwork::populateFromDB, static_cast<void*>(&a), &error) != SQLITE_OK)
    sqlite_free(error)
```

Or as a `friend` function instead:

```
class artwork
{
    friend int getArtwork(void*, int, char**, char**);
private:
    std::string title;
    std::string creator;
};    
int getArtwork(void* object, int, char** data, char**)
{
    if (artwork* const art = static_cast<artwork*>(object))
    {
        art->title = data[1];
        art->creator = data[2];
    }
    return 0;
}

artwork a;
char* error = nullptr;
if (sqlite3_exec(db, tQuery.c_str(), &getArtwork, static_cast<void*>(&a), &error) != SQLITE_OK)
    sqlite_free(error)
```